# Using relection to find a type's implementation of an interface method

Tags: c#, reflection

Consider this example:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    string GetFoo();
}

public class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    public string GetFoo()
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
}
```

Now say I have an instance of a `MethodInfo` object that represents the abstract interface method:

```
MethodInfo abstractMethod = typeof(MyInterface).GetMethod("GetFoo");
```

I would like to obtain a `MethodInfo` instance for the exact method a given type uses to implement the interface method.

For an abstract/virtual class (not interface) method, this can be done:

```
MethodInfo implementation = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods().Single(m => m.GetBaseDefinition() == abstractMethod);
```

How can I do this for an interface method? Checking method names is not sufficient in case the type implicitly declares the method.

Comment: Why do you need this?  What are you actually trying to do?